# How to render a report band of a jasper report only when a subreport inside the band is not empty?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a main report which queries a list of items from the database in the detail band, and another detail band which contains a sub report that renders once for every record. I want this second detail band to be rendered only when the sub report within it is not empty.

I tried to get the REPORT_COUNT from the sub report into a return variable and set the `Print when expression` parameter as `$V{SUBREPORT_ITEMS_ROW_COUNT} != null && $V{SUBREPORT_ITEMS_ROW_COUNT} > 0` but it looks like the return variable is computed after the band is rendered, so it can't see the variable even it being returned correctly.

What else can i do?

**UPDATE**
Here is the main report's JRXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.1.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.1.0  -->
<!-- 2016-01-21T10:03:49 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="PlanoDeContasDetalhado" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="9fa6ae6c-0db5-4324-a65d-f0d61a8f30bb">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="SCA Banco de dados bagual"/>
    <style name="NIVEL">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{PLCTA15COD}.trim().length() == 1]]></conditionExpression>
            <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#CFCFCF" fontSize="15" isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <parameter name="EMPRICOD" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <parameter name="ID_SETOR" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <parameter name="CAMPO_DATA" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="DATA1" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <parameter name="DATA2" class="java.util.Date"/>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["C:\\Users\\Mateus\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\AtualyRelatorios\\jasper\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="CON_ITENS" class="java.sql.Connection" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select
plcta15cod,
plcta30codedit,
plcta60descr
from planodecontas
order by plcta15cod]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="PLCTA15COD" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="PLCTA30CODEDIT" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="PLCTA60DESCR" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <title>
        <band height="82" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="510" height="26" uuid="2fa3702f-ff66-41a6-81e9-7dbbbd791233"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <font size="18" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Detalhamento do plano de contas]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="26" width="510" height="15" uuid="f23a5d3d-a05d-4e9c-9053-492e635cde26"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="11" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Receitas & Despesas]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="18" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="NIVEL" x="0" y="0" width="80" height="18" uuid="2db15faa-e12e-4fc3-a5ae-956d454e50da"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{PLCTA30CODEDIT}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement style="NIVEL" x="80" y="0" width="475" height="18" uuid="bbcbea9e-2b83-4cd5-aa1e-2daea32f33a0"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{PLCTA15COD}.trim().replaceAll(".","-")
+ $F{PLCTA15COD}.trim().replaceAll(".","-")
+ $F{PLCTA60DESCR}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
        <band height="4">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="-20" y="0" width="595" height="4" uuid="572867ad-8bb8-4664-9ae9-a1120c102430"/>
                <subreportParameter name="EMPRICOD">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{EMPRICOD}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="ID_SETOR">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{ID_SETOR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="CAMPO_DATA">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{CAMPO_DATA}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="DATA1">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{DATA1}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="DATA2">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{DATA2}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="PLCTA15COD">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{PLCTA15COD}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "PlanoDeContasDetalhadoItens.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: What kind of datasource are you using?, do you have other elements (that are not supposed to rendered) in the detail band or only the subreport? Do you manage to give a short [mcve] with some jrxml?

Comment: SQL datasource. No other elements in the subreport band, just the sub-report. Gonna update the question with the main report JRXML

Comment: AFIK, there is no way you can have the information before the query is actually executed in subreport (and its to late since the 4px detail is already created). Your work around can be (create a field in main report holding info if  there are records in subreport, join the table of subreport query) or make the detailband only 1px and live with it...

Comment: Yeah just what i thought, guess i'll have to work with the 1px band. Thanks.

Comment: You could teroetically load the JasperPrint (after you have filled), and remove the 1px band... but to have sense you need to move all other components below... look like overkill, move the subreport into your other band and live with it....

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to create a Master-Detail report? if yes (I don't know if I misunderstand your question, but that is my answer):  I used to have the the subreport in the same band (detail) , and pass the master parameter to the subreport , into the subreport the query will use it, so if the master parameter doesnt come in the main query it wont show anything into the subreport.
I hope this be usefull for you.

Comment: Thanks super mario, that way the sub report won't show, but the band on the master report in which the subreport is located will still be visible, and that is what i was trying to avoid.